# take words out of string with Reg

Tags: regex

Sorry, I am not a reg expert. I would like to ask for help how to take certain words out of a string.

Here is a example, I have a long string like this:

```
   [SubClassOf(<file:F:/Projects/OIL/DAMLOilEd/ontologies/ka.daml#Lecturer> <file:F:/Projects/OIL/DAMLOilEd/ontologies/ka.daml#Person>)]
```

I need to extract the words Lecturer and Person out of the long string. The reg will perform something like start with `#` and end with `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything between `#` and `>`:

```
'(?<=#)[^#>]*(?=>)'
```

This will match everything (excluding `#` and `>`) inside `#>` and the result won't include the `#` and `>` at starting and ending.

Comment: But I want this reg to be able to apply to other cases too, not just this case. Therefore, we cant have Person and lecturer in it. I believe

Comment: @StevenLiu Anything between `#` and `>`?

Comment: @StevenLiu updated, result won't include `#` and `>`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want any word between those two characters to be detected, the regex would be:

```
 #[^#>]*>
```

This will match everything between a `#` and a `>`, including the `#` and `>` themselves. It assumes the word itself does not contain a `#` or a `>`.

Comment: is that possible to not include # and > in the final result match

Comment: `(?<=#)[^#>]*(?=>)` should do that.

Answer (score 1):

Improving @Jahid answer. Use:

`(?<=#)[^#>]+(?=>)`

The parenthesis are respectively, lookbehind and lookahead [assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php).

The main class (square brackets) matches everything but `#` and `>` characters